# Best Web .net Query Builder

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, report

Hey all I am looking for a web bases query builder for non programmers it has to be web and it has to be .net dont care if c# or vb.net I perfer c# but thats ok.

Let me know what you think is best and why?

Thanks!

Comment: What kind of queries do you want to build (LINQ, SQL, etc.)?

Comment: What is .net query builder? What kind of query? How can be for non programmers if it's in c# or VB?

Comment: Do you mean something like a URI editor? Where you can modify query parameters for POST requests?

Comment: I hear "query builder" and I'm thinking "SSMS"... but that clearly isn't c# or VB... and isn't suitable for non-programmers. Please clarify what you mean by "query builder"? Do you mean, for example, a  UI around something like Sql Server Reporting Services? Or what?

Comment: Do you mean a SQL syntax highlighting type builder?

Comment: I am talking about something like this: http://devtools.korzh.com/query-builder-component/

Answer (score 4):

I have used Korzh EasyQuery.NET on a past project, and the clients were very pleased with the result.  We used it for ad-hoc reporting, but it can easily be modified to work in any database query environment.

It includes a configuration tool so you can alias all your database tables, views, columns, etc so your users see names that make sense to them.  It is available as both WebForms (ASP.NET) or WinForms controls, and the WebForms version includes the option for Ajaxified presentation.

The tool is free to use if you don't mind the Korzh watermarks on your app page that hosts it, otherwise its something like $600 to buy a license which removes the watermarks and includes some support time as well.

[no, I don't work for them...I've just used their tools]

Comment: Yes, I can recommend Korzh EasyQuery.NET also. It does not like traditional "Acess like" query building, but users love it. I do not know why...

Answer (score 0):

[image] 
[EasyQuery:](http://demo.easyquerybuilder.com/)

query builder and advanced search components

SQL query builder with human language interface

see this link : http://demo.easyquerybuilder.com/